# Programmatically get highest outcome formula with 3 variables and given condition

Tags: algorithm, variables

I have a formula that contains 3 variables. Let's name them `x1`, `x2` and `x3`.
The user can enter a number which is the sum of these variables and stored in `z`, so `z=10` equals `x1 + x2 +x3 =10` and `z=20` equals `x1+x2+x3 = 20`.

The formula will have an outcome like 2000 or 4591, etc. Now I would like to find the `x1`, `x2`, `x3` for `z` such that it has the highest outcome. 
`x1= 2 x2=3 x3=5` might give 2500, but `x1=3 x2=6 x3=1` might give 2983, etc. for `z =10`

So If `z =10` I can try a for loop and start with `X1 =0`, `X2=0`, `X3=10` and then loop through all situations and save the results, but this seems inefficient to me. I would like to find a direction for how I can solve this efficiently for different `z` values and give something back like:

For z=10 the highest value is achieved by `x1=4 x2=3 x3=4` with the outcome 3465.

As for program language, I can use PHP, JS, Java, C++, Haskell. So it's not about the language but more about how to solve this problem in general.

Comment: Look into Linear Programming. You may need to learn a little math and find a matrix library.

Comment: Do you have to always do the same set of operations on the three numbers, or can you change both the set of operations and the three numbers?

Comment: @ChatterOne The operations are always the same. You can only change the three numbers. The three numbers should always add up to `z`

Comment: @Helper What are the bounds on x1, x2, x3? Are they limited to the nonnegative integers?

Comment: An answer depends very much on how the outcome is calculated. Could you give some details?

Comment: Your final example seems wrong: x1 + x2 + x3 = 4 + 3 + 4 = 11, not 10.

Comment: Your description suggests that the `x` values must be non-negative integers.  Is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, it seems you are describing the [Assignment Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_problem)

> The problem instance has a number of agents and a number of tasks. Any agent can be assigned to perform any task, incurring some cost that may vary depending on the agent-task assignment. It is required to perform all tasks by assigning exactly one agent to each task and exactly one task to each agent in such a way that the total cost of the assignment is minimized.

In your case, the "agents" are the 3 inputed values and the "tasks" are the variables x1, x2, and x3. Your cost function would just be the formula (but modified so that bigger numbers return a smaller cost - maybe something like `1-formula`)

To solve, this you're going to need to use the [Hungarian Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_algorithm). I'm not going to go through all the details of it (but [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/hungarian-algorithm-assignment-problem-set-1-introduction/) explanation from GeeksForGeeks explains it pretty well). Basically, you need to complete an NxN cost matrix, and then do some operations on that matrix to find the optimal solution. The Hungarian Algorithm is O(n^3) - which is far more efficient than brute forcing it (which is a staggering O(n!))

Comment: Why do you say brute force algorithm is O(n!)? What do you call n? z?

Comment: @Damien In big-O notation, n is used to refer to the size of the inputs, which is in this case 3 (x1, x2, x3). A brute force algorithm would be O(n!) because the number of permutations of n elements is n!.

Comment: In this case, n = 3

Answer (score 0):

Given the apparent constraints, I'm unclear on where you're stuck.  You merely need to iterate through the available values, evaluating the hidden formula -- I'll call it function `f` -- for each combination.

Since your function is of unspecified format, you have no way to predict one value from others: you have to evaluate each triple individually.

Here is pseudo-code

```
max = MININT     # smallest possible integer
for x1 in interval[0, 10]
    for x2 in interval[0, 10-x1]
        x3 = 10 - (x1+x2)
        value = f(x1, x2, x3)
        if value > max
            max = value
            coeff = [x1, x2, x3]

print "max value achieved at", coeff, "with a value of", max
```

Does that get you going?